# Subtracting the current NDVI image from the previous NDVI temporal cube image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to perform change detection by subtracting indexes.

I am still new to GEE.

I am taking advantage of the structure of an existing script to try to achieve my goal.

I am generating an image from NDVI-quality temporal cube (qualityMosaic).

I cannot subtract each 'current' NDVI-image from the previous NDVI-image temporal cube image.

How can I concatenate this subtraction?

I forgot to say that I need the result to amaze the date metadata.

Below is the script.

---

```
// Define time interval to composite scenes
var date_start="2018-01-01";
var date_end="2018-12-30";

// define mask functions

function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
// empiric mask
var maskNotValid = function(image) {
  var cloudMask = image.select(Band_BLUE).lt(1500).and(image.select(Band_LSWIR).gt(600))
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask);
}

var L8coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(Region)
.filterDate(date_start,date_end)
.map(maskL8sr)
.map(function(image){
  return image.rename(['blueblue', 'B1', 'green', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'brigtemp', 'B8', 'B9', 'pixel_qa', 'B11']);//padroniza a B7 
})
.select(['B1', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa']);

// merge collections 
var image_collection_type = L8coll;
print (image_collection_type)

// define band names
if (image_collection_type){
  var Band_BLUE='B1'
  var Band_RED='B3'
  var Band_NIR='B4'
  var Band_SSWIR='B5'
  var Band_LSWIR='B7'
  var resolution=30
}

// Calc spectral index
var add_NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.expression('float(b("'+ Band_NIR + '") - b("' + Band_RED + '")) / (b("' +  Band_NIR + '") + b("' + Band_RED+ '"))').rename('NDVI'))
};

//Add date variable
var add_date = function(image) {
    var timestamp = image.metadata('system:time_start');
    return image.addBands(timestamp);
};

var get_date=function(d){
    return d.set("date",ee.Date(d.get('median')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
};

// Change Detection
var addChangeQualityBand = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference([Band_LSWIR, Band_NIR]).rename('Change'))
};

var addNotChangeQualityBand = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference([Band_NIR, Band_RED]).rename('NotChamge'))
};




// Define Maximum NBR
function get_post_composite (date_start, date_end){
  var image_collection = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection_type)
    .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
    .map(maskNotValid)
    .map(addChangeQualityBand)
    .map(add_NDVI)
    .map(add_date)
    .filterBounds(Region);
  var composite = image_collection.qualityMosaic('Change');

  return composite
}

// Define Maximum NDVI
function get_pre_composite (date_start, date_end,image_collection_type){
  var image_collection = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection_type) 
    .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
    .map(maskNotValid)
    .map(addNotChangeQualityBand)
    .map(add_NDVI)
    .map(add_date)
    .filterBounds(Region);
  var composite = image_collection.qualityMosaic('NotChamge');
  return composite
}

var post_composite=get_post_composite (date_start, date_end,image_collection_type)
var pre_composite=get_pre_composite (date_start, date_end,image_collection_type)
var subtract_post_pre_composite=post_composite.subtract(pre_composite)

//clip
var post_composite = post_composite.clipToCollection(Region)
var pre_composite = pre_composite.clipToCollection(Region)

//plot
Map.addLayer( pre_composite , {bands: [Band_LSWIR, Band_NIR, Band_RED], min: [0, 0, 0], max: [4000, 4000, 4000]}, 'NDVI maximum composite');
Map.addLayer( post_composite , {bands: [Band_LSWIR, Band_NIR, Band_RED], min: [0, 0, 0], max: [4000, 4000, 4000]}, 'NBR maximum composite');
```